# NSDataDetector type NSTextCheckingTypeTransitInformation - is it available for iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdatadetector, datadetectortypes

I use the following code, sending a recent UPS tracking number (string), to see if the NSDataDetector will detect the tracking number as a match for the NSTextCheckingTypeTransitInformation type. The method returns zero results. When I type this same tracking number into the Notes iOS app, it gives me the option to view the tracking link ("Track Shipment").

```
- (void)checkTrackingNumber:(NSString*)trackingNumber {

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSDataDetector *detector = [NSDataDetector dataDetectorWithTypes:NSTextCheckingTypeTransitInformation error:&error];
    [detector enumerateMatchesInString:trackingNumber
                               options:0
                                 range:NSMakeRange(0, [trackingNumber length])
                            usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *result, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop) {
                                // Do Something Here
                                NSLog(@"result.URL is: %@",result.URL);
                            }];
}
```

Is there some reason that the above code would not work in an iOS app for a valid tracking number?

Comment: it checks NSTextCheckingAirlineKey and NSTextCheckingFlightKey. information when you use NSTextCheckingTypeTransitInformation, it would not check UPS Tracking number

Comment: Thanks! You can post that as an answer if you want. Also, do you know if there is any way I can check package tracking, like the Notes app does?

Comment: you can create your custom TextCheckingEnum where you need to put condition for that. "can you share sample UPS number" and based on pattern you can convert that content with blue color underline text in label or textview with attributed text.

Comment: OK, thanks. I thought there might be something built in to iOS that I had missed. Bummer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it checks NSTextCheckingAirlineKey and NSTextCheckingFlightKey. information when you use NSTextCheckingTypeTransitInformation, it would not check UPS Tracking number